# How many versions of the Merovingian exist in The Matrix series?

Tags: the-matrix

Is there any information or indication in the series about the existence of multiple versions of the Merovingian within the Matrix?

Specifically, are there distinct versions of this character across different movies, or do the changes we see in films like *The Matrix Resurrections* (2021) reflect a continuous development of the same character?

Comment: *Mark my words boy, Mark them well, I have survived your predecessors and I will survive you.*